# How do I stop Windows 10 Aero Snap keyboard shortcuts from opening the start menu?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, start-menu, aero-snap

When I use the Aero Snap hotkeys (e.g. `Win + Left` for snapping a window) sometimes the Start Menu pops open, taking focus away from the window I just positioned and not bringing up the other window selection choices.  I'm pretty sure this happens when I don't hit `Win` and the arrow keys at the same time.  E.G. if I press `Win` and `Left` simultaneously, Aero Snap works as expected, but if I press `Win` *then* `Left`, it will bring up the Start Menu.

I also use `Win + Up + Up` to take a window from the side snap to full screen which I would like to have work as well.  This one is less important since there are other shortcuts to make a window full screen, but it'd still be really nice to keep using that shortcut.

I seem to remember this not being a problem before I reinstalled my OS recently, and this issue is very annoying.

Is there any way to prevent the Start Menu from popping up in these cases aside from disabling the Start Menu `Win` shortcut?  I still use `Win` to bring up the search for quick access to applications, so I'd prefer not to outright disable that shortcut.  I know that `CTRL + ESC` will open the start menu, but just hitting `Win` is so much nicer since `CTRL + ESC` is awkward to reach.

I'm running Windows 10 Pro version 1803 build `17134.407`

Comment: Just to rule out any possible known issues, you should install KB4467682, and see if you still have the problem.  However, I was unable to reproduce the behavior you describe.  After using Aero Snap, I had to hit the Windows key, multiple times before the Start Menu was displayed (and change focus to the desktop)

Comment: The Start Menu will appear if the arrow key is not pressed fast enough.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that a Windows update (although I'm not entirely sure which one) fixed the issue.  The Aero Snap hotkeys are working as expected again without the Start Menu popping up all the time.

Thanks to Ramhound for the suggestion to simply update.